# Is there any way to use the value of a cell as the "pointer" of a parameter in a function?

Tags: excel, pointers, excel-formula

I'm trying to do an excel to keep track of my transactions.
I need to know if is there a way to do this:

```
//Value of A1=3;
//Value of A2=1; A3=4;
=SUM(A2:A(A1))
//The process would be:
  A1=3, so, =SUM(A2:A3) = 1+4
```

And to have: 5 in that cell.//1+4

I can't express myself, sorry.

Any clues?

---

SOLVED:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("C" &T2&":N" &U1))
```

In where C is the letter of the first "vertex", T2 his number, N is the second "vertex" and U1 the number of that vertex.

Comment: Take a look at INDEX and see if you can make that work for you.  It is my understanding that INDIRECT is a volatile function.  Which means it will recalculate anytime some on the worksheet changes.  Not a big deal for a small worksheet, but if used repeatedly may become a bigger issue.

Comment: @ForwardEd Well, now I know, but I doný know any other way; the excel sheet is to calculate my current balance, inserting data from emails that I get when I buy things btw